# How to get Django Organization Specific Microsoft Authentication working?

Tags: python, django, authentication, security

I know this is a broad question. I am currently trying to figure out how to get Django app to only accept organization specific Microsoft accounts. I do not need a step by step answer but some guidance on what I should go research or do.